# Jetpack plugin (ShareDaddy): Prevent share buttons showing on custom post types?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-jetpack

I noticed ShareDaddy has "Show sharing buttons on this post" for default post types but not for custom post types. I'm guessing I need to add something in `'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')`. Does anybody know what I need to add in order for "Show sharing buttons on this post" to show up for custom post types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ShareDaddy uses two filter hooks either `the_content` or `the_excerpt` this means that your custom post type theme template file has to use one of these two functions `the_content();` or `the_excerpt();`.

### Update

Ok I guess i didn't get the question. So to add the metabox to your custom post type add this:

```
// Hook things in, late enough so that add_meta_box() is defined and make sure you already registered you post type.
    if (is_admin()){
        add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_plugin_meta_boxes' );
        add_action( 'save_post', 'save_sharing_box' );
    }

// This function tells WP to add the sharing "meta box"
function add_plugin_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'sharing_meta', __( 'Sharing', 'sharedaddy' ), 'sharing_meta_box_content', 'CUSTOM POST TYPE NAME', 'advanced', 'high' );

}

function save_sharing_box( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;

    // Record sharing disable
    if ( 'CUSTOM POST TYPE NAME' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            if ( isset( $_POST['sharing_status_hidden'] ) ) {
                if ( !isset( $_POST['enable_post_sharing'] ) )
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'sharing_disabled', 1 );
                else
                    delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'sharing_disabled' );
            }
        }
    }

  return $post_id;
}
```

and change `CUSTOM POST TYPE NAME` to you actual custom post type name.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've misunderstood your answer or if I wasn't clear enough in my question. Basically, I want the metabox for "Show sharing buttons on this post" for each post in my custom post type to show. I assume I can control this by adding an item to the supports array.

Comment: @jwp: sorry i didn't get the question. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an older post, but I found this site when searching for an answer, then found the real answer somewhere else, so I thought i would share it for anyone else having a similar issue.

I created 2 Custom Post-Types and wanted the Share buttons in Jetpack to show up.

I thought it would probably be a code in the functions.php file, as that's where I got the rest of the functionality for the Custom Post-Types.

In fact, I simply went to the Settings->Sharing menu. The Custom Post-Types were there in the list and all I needed to do was put a check in each box to make it work like I wanted.

No extra coding, just a simple check mark.

Answer (score -2):

Solution is editing jetpack/modules/publicize/publicize.php

line 354 change by this

```
function post_type_is_publicizeable( $post_type ) {
    if ( 'Your_custom_post' == $post_type )
        return true;
    if ( 'post' == $post_type )
        return true;

    return post_type_supports( $post_type, 'publicize' );
}
```

Comment: The solution is **never** editing the plugin directly. Any changes you make will be lost in future plugin versions. Jetpack provides some [developer tools](http://jetpack.me/support/jetpack-for-developers/), including some filters that may provide a much better option that editing and re-editing the plugin itself.